# Clock won't syncronize and drift

Tags: sync, clock

I have an Ubuntu server

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
Linux lab01 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm having tons of issues setting up the clock and making it synchronize.

I was trying to make chrony work with no luck

Currently my `chrony.conf` is

```
pool 0.pool.ntp.org burst
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1 -1
maxdistance 12000
```

I've added the maxdistance trying to fix the issue.

The command  `sudo chronyc sources -v`

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? ns2.fibertelecom.it           2   6     3    59  -278.5s[-278.5s] +/-   53ms
^? ns3.fibertelecom.it           3   6     3    59  -277.7s[-277.7s] +/-   38ms
^? ns1.fibertelecom.it           2   6     3    60  -276.1s[-276.1s] +/-   35ms
^? nettuno.ntp.irh.it            2   6     3    60  -276.9s[-276.9s] +/-   11ms
```

and `chronyc tracking`

```
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000001 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 86.704 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

What should I do?

EDIT `date` shows the correct date and time

Comment: What time does the command 'date' give, how much is it off compared to actual time ? The ntp-protocol will not adjust time if it is more than an hour or so off.Linux expects systm(bios clock to be in UTC, Also verify that your bios-clock is approximately correct, and keeps its setting  over power-downs and reboots.

Comment: thanks for the downvote, appreciated with no comments

Comment: @SorenA `date` shows the correct date/time